# html into input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem to load html into input field value. As the pictures.

A) When i save it:

[image]

B) When i load it:

[image]

C) The code used for create input field:

```
var templateField;
templateField = '<input type="text" id="' + fieldName + '" maxlength="' + args.maxlength + '" value="' + args.value + '"/>';
$controller.append(templateField);
```

Note:
I can't append *templateField* first and after that do an *innerHtml* because i don't know what type of value will be (date, boolean, etc). This controller is used to create fields dynamic. I have this problem just when the type of value is String and the user put html values at the field.

Comment: See if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: maybe one of your varible contains a double code.

Comment: Looks like you have an XXS vulnerability. escape user input.

Comment: `value="' + document.createTextNode(args.value) + '"`

Comment: @ZachLeighton, i call htmlEncode passing 'teste /">' by parameter and return is 'teste /"&gt;'. But when render this value into input, it just show 'teste /'.

Comment: @Brian, this code return to input value="[object Text]"

Comment: @epascarello, was used escape to save and undescape to load into input value. But, when render the value, happend this topic error

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the values before setting them:

```
function replaceStr(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#39;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");

}

value="' + replaceStr(args.value) + '"
```

The single quote replacement is optional in this case.